# Typescript, unable to read an array stored in sessionStorage

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have an arroy stored as a String in session Storage, and I want to read it, add one element, and set it back.

```
trackNavHistory = (path: String) => {
    let historyArr : Array<String> = sessionStorage.getItem("navHistory")?.split(",");
    historyArr.push(path)
    sessionStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(historyArr));
  }
```

So basically historyArr should be an array of strings that is read from sessionStorage.

But it returns

> Type 'string[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'String[]'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'String[]'

And then I cant set the item back.
Whats the issue?

I have also tried

```
trackNavHistory = (path: String) => {
    let historyArr : Array<String> = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("navHistory"));
    historyArr.push(path)
    sessionStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(historyArr));
  }
```

> Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'string'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type
> 'string'.ts(2345)

Comment: Your transform in and out should match. You do not `JSON.parse` when reading, but you `JSON.stringify` when writing. What you do to write and what you do with the read data should be inverses of each other, so don't try to just cowboy something.

Comment: @crashmstr thats what im doing in the second example, but it crashes too

Comment: Think about what the error is telling you. `sessionStorage.getItem` is typed to return `string | nulll`. `JSON.stringify` takes a `string`. You need to "prove" to the compiler that `getItem` does not return null. Also, you are missing the `key` parameter for your `setItem` call.

Comment: Also, that is not a "crash". That is a compiler error where TypeScript is telling you that you've done something that may not be correct from a type-safety perspective.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between *runtime* and *compile time*. That error is a compiler error. You're not having trouble with sessionStorage because your code isn't compiling *at all*, much less *running*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common practice to define `string` type in typescript is using `string` keyword started from small letter.

Your second approach is correct. You should use `JSON.stringify` before persisting data in `sessionStorage` and `JSON.parse` to get your array back from JSON

`let historyArr` is declared as a variable which can holds only array of strings `let historyArr : Array<String>` but since `sessionStorage.getItem` can return either `string` or `null` and `JSON.parse(null) === null` typescript complains that you can not assign the result of this operiotn (`JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("navHistory"));historyArr.push(path)`) to `historyArr` variable.

I would suggest to do it this way:

```
const trackNavHistory = (path: string) => {
    let navHistory = sessionStorage.getItem('navHistory');

    if (!navHistory) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('navHistory', JSON.stringify([path]));
        return;
    }

    const historyArr: Array<string> = JSON.parse(navHistory);

    historyArr.push(path);

    sessionStorage.setItem('navHistory', JSON.stringify(historyArr));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your get and set should be inverses of each other - don't try to cowboy the JSON.

Secondly, this is not a "crash" but a TypeScript compiler error. TypeScript is helping you with telling you that you need to check for there not being a value (`getItem` return type is `string | null`, and you need `string` type)

To solve this

1. we first get the session data
2. we check for data to not be null, undefined, etc.
3. if we have data, we parse it and put into the array
4. we then push onto the array, which is either empty (no session data) or filled (session data)
5. we finally set the session data back

```
const trackNavHistory = (path: String) => {
  const data = sessionStorage.getItem("navHistory");
  let historyArr = [];
  if (data) {
    historyArr = JSON.parse(data);
  }
  historyArr.push(path);
  sessionStorage.setItem("navHistory", JSON.stringify(historyArr));
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBDYBrAcogbgCQJbRHgE8YBeGACgAdEoALALhgGUFcwBzASjID4YA3gCgYMUJFgATWojIwIAUwgRc4VoUQcFAOi1QAklAUBbCgCIwWPAWJmuAbhEwANgth18UQkQCC8eHIA2gC6jqK4AGaU0lCIPMKioh42vv5yAFLMAPJo2jTwihQxcWEwAL5OyV7EfvB5AK4QdNS0dA5OisqqYOpIWtqKBkamFlae3mYANDCZOQNsnJFEFFXetVztFUA)